# Flutter async function with for loop is not returning

Tags: flutter, dart, for-loop, google-cloud-firestore

I have a really weird behavior right not inside my app and I have absolutely no idea what is wrong with my code. That is my function:

```
Future<List<UniversityImage>> getImagesForUniversity(
    University university,
  ) async {
    List<UniversityImage> images = [];
    var imagesQuerySnapshot = await firestoreInstance
        .collection(keys.universities)
        .doc(university.id)
        .collection(keys.images)
        .get();

    print(imagesQuerySnapshot.docs.length);   // <-- gets printed

    for (var image in imagesQuerySnapshot.docs) {
      Map<String, dynamic> imageData = image.data();
      images.add(
        UniversityImage(
          id: imageData[keys.id]!,
          index: imageData[keys.index]!,
          universityId: imageData[keys.universityId]!,
          downloadUrl: imageData[keys.downloadUrl]!,
        ),
      );
    }

    print('length:');     // <-- not getting printed
    print(images.length); // <-- not getting printed
    return images;
  }
```

A simple function that gets some documents from Firebase Firestore. It should add each image to `images` and in the end I just want to return all the `images`.

But somehow my code gets stuck inside the `for-loop`!

What am I missing here? Let me know if you need any more info!

Comment: Most likely an exception is being thrown within your for-loop, and it's being caught somewhere up the stack. Try surrounding your loop with a try catch, and see if you get an exception in the catch block.

Comment: @MichaelHorn and what exactly should I catch?

Comment: For the sake of debugging, just catch any error that's thrown, like so: `try { ... } catch (error) { print(error); }` and see what you find. Once you know what's happening, you can handle it properly